# How do you properly structure JSON for a file field when testing Services with Postman?

Tags: json, drupal, drupal-7, postman

In Drupal 7 I successfully set up Services (I'm using REST, and session authentication) and can authenticate and then post/create a new node with Postman using this JSON:

```
{
    "type":"my_content_type", 
    "title":"My Title", 
    "body":{ "und" :[ {"value":"Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet" }] }
}
```

When I add a file field to the content type, adding this JSON doesn't work for uploading a file:

```
"field_file":{ "und" :[ {"file":"/Desktop/somefile.csv"}]}
```

The response returns "file field is required" (I have the field set to required). So clearly that bit of JSON isn't working.

How do you properly format this so you can upload a file using Postman?